# How to use Contain with multiple values in C#, LINQ to pull record

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am working on .NET 6 application with entity framework core. I am creating record search query using LINQ where I am expecting to receive List of string. No of string values are not fixed and will varies. How I can use List in LINQ contain?

```
List<string> Roles = new List<string>() { "Business Analyst", "Business Analysis Lead", "Application Support Analyst" };

var records = (from jobProfile in db.JobProfiles
          where jobProfile.Role.Contains(Roles) 
          select jobProfile).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var records = (
   from jobProfile in db.JobProfiles
   where jobProfile.Role.Any(r => Roles.Contains(r.Name))
   select jobProfile
).ToList();
```

or with fluent interface:

```
var records = 
   db
   .JobProfiles
   .Where(jp => jp.Role.Any(r => Roles.Contains(r.Name)))
   .ToList();
```

`Roles` can be any `IEnumerable`. EF will convert the method call to an `IN` clause.

Note that if the source (here `db.JobProfiles`) stopped being an `IQueryable` and was instead an `IEnumerable`, then you would be using an O(n) `.Contains` call. As long as it's EF you can use an `IEnumerable` for `Roles` since `.Contains` is not actually called in that case, but for LINQ to Objects you would want to make sure that it's a Set of some kind instead.

If `Role` is a `string` property rather than an entity, then it's a bit simpler:

```
var records = (
   from jobProfile in db.JobProfiles
   where Roles.Contains(jobProfile.Role)
   select jobProfile
).ToList();
```

or with fluent interface:

```
var records = 
   db
   .JobProfiles
   .Where(jp => Roles.Contains(jp.Role))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Dave ... My list is as  

List<string> Roles = new List<string>() { "Business Analyst", "Business Analysis Lead", "Application Support Analyst" };

so what will be `name` in this case... where jobProfile.Role.Any(r => names.Contains(r.Name))

Comment: @K.Z It depends on your model. Is `Role` a `string` property? Then it will be `jp => names.Contains(jp.Role)`. I was assuming that `Role` was an entity type.

Comment: jobProfile is DbSet and Role is one the property of class `jobProfile' Roles are list of string as List<string> Roles...

Comment: correct 'Role` is string property

Comment: @K.Z oh I notice now that you named the list `Roles` but then referred to it as `names` in the query. I am assuming that `names` and `List<string> Roles` are the same thing.

Comment: my mistake, it should be Roles and not names

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter by where your Role-list contains the job profile role:

```
var records = (from jobProfile in db.JobProfiles
               where Roles.Contains(jobProfile.Role) 
               select jobProfile).ToList();
```

...or in fluent:

```
var records = db.JobProfiles
    .Where(x => Roles.Contains(x.Role))
    .ToList();
```